# LVM: regenerate a UUID?

Tags: lvm, uuid

I have some virtual machines which were clones of the same original disk image, which contained some LVM volumes.  When I clone these, I end up with multiple LVM volumes (albeit on different hosts) which have the same 'unique' ID.  Is there any way I can get LVM to change the UUID of an existing volume?

Answer (score 10):

```
pvchange --uuid /physical/volume/path
vgchange --uuid /volume/group/name
```

Comment: you can't vgchange --uuid on a vg with active logical volumes.

Comment: `vgimportclone /physical/volume/path` helped me, at least a bit.

Comment: @Ned64 this should be the accepted answer ! works for me.

Comment: @LiMar OK, thanks for the feedback, I wrote an answer. Feel free to vote for it :-)

Answer (score 8):

According to [its man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-vgimportclone/), the command `vgimportclone` will do the work for you:

```
vgimportclone /physical/volume/path
```

This is used for importing a volume group (VG) from a cloned physical volume (PV), e.g. after a snapshot or other duplicated PV.

Answer (score 1):

`pvchange` was not working for me, it kept avoiding the volume with

> WARNING: Not using device /dev/sdc for PV
>   C0s0Wg-HcnQ-LOP3-QwmR-dhSX-4wW1-hRhxm3.   WARNING: PV
>   C0s0Wg-HcnQ-LOP3-QwmR-dhSX-4wW1-hRhxm3 prefers device /dev/sdb because
>   device is used by LV.   Device /dev/sdc excluded by a filter.

Ultimately, `wipefs /dev/sdc` was the solution, after which I simply used

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc
```